# Remove duplicate with start and end character in sql

Tags: sql, regex

I have a string and need to remove duplicate by select statement in ORACLE SQL.
e.g: 'apple-HenryHenry(Male)-SunnySunny(Female)-apple'
I want to resulting output would be: 'apple-Henry(Male)-Sunny(Female)-apple'
Everyone help me

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('apple-HenryHenry(Male)-SunnySunny(Female)-apple', '([[:alnum:]]+)(\1)+', '\1') AS result
  FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query mostly correct, but it will remove double letters from words, an duplicate parts of words (like `banana` -> `bana`).

You can use something like this

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('apple-HenryHenry(Male)-SunnySunny(Female)-apple', '(^|\W)(\w+)\2+(\W|$)', '\1\2\3') AS result
  FROM dual;
```

Here `(^|\W)(\w+)\2+(\W|$)` matches words, surrounded by non word symbols or string boundaries, that consists of two or more equal parts.

It is not ideal, because it will modify `haha` -> `ha`. If it is guaranteed that both parts of duplicated word start with upper letter, you can use `(^|\W)([A-Z]\w*)\2+(\W|$)` instead.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('bananabanana-HenryHenry(Male)-SunnySunny(Female)-apple', '(^|\W)([A-Z]\w*)\2+(\W|$)', '\1\2\3') AS result
  FROM dual;
-- Outputs: bananabanana-Henry(Male)-Sunny(Female)-apple
```